# Change div width based on condition in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular6

I want to change the div width based on the following condition,

```html
<div [ngStyle]="'width': selectedTab =='Home' ? '50%' : '100%'">

</div>
```

I am getting the tab which has been selected in "**selectedTab**".

I have two tabs.

1) Index

2) Home

If I select Index tab, The div width should be "**100%**". Incase If I select home tab, the div width should be "**50%**". I have written [ngStyle] condition but it is not working.

Please help me how can I handle this situation.

Comment: Might try a two way binding that you change based on which tab you are currently on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<div [style.width]="selectedTab =='Home' ? '50%' : '100%'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngStyle` for this.

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-div-width-based-on-condition-in-angular-6?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<div [ngStyle]="{
    'width.%': selectedTab =='Home' ? '50' : '100',
    'background-color': 'red'
  }">>
  div
</div>
```